# Can I set the start point of a bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a closed bezier loop that insists on a particular point being the start/end. Is there a way to change which point is considered the start, as in which point represents 0.0 evaluation time? I've deleted and rejoined segments all over, and every time I close the loop, it goes back to the same point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thumb rule is that basically, for a closed spline, the last segment created upon closing a curve is will contain the first vertex of the curve spline.

So if you want to make a certain vertex the first one, then delete the segment immediately before or after it to make that vertex the starting point. Then close that spline again.

As far as I know there is no easy way to determine which of the gaping vertex will actually become the first one. And on 2D curves, you can't tell them apart easily because there are no normal arrow indicators to guide you.

If you don't like the outcome though, you can always open the curve again, and call *Switch Direction* operator, either from the Search menu, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> context menu, or *Segments > Switch Direction*, reverse the result as desired then close the spline again.

[image]

For 2.8+ you can also activate the addon *Curve Tools* from the preferences, and under the *Edit* tab of the 3D View sidebar under *Utilities > Set First Point* allows setting an arbitrary point as first for selected splines.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Enable the *Bsurfaces* addon, in *Edit* mode select the desired vertex and go into the *N panel > Edit > Bsurfaces > Set First Points*.

For Blender 2.7, *T* menu > *Tools* > *Bsurfaces* > *Set First Points*.

Comment: works like magic

Comment: I gave up on Bsurfaces because the window is not popping up anywhere intuitive.
This function should be standard in the menu of bezier lines, it's a commonly used function and it really doesn't make any sense that it can't be found there straight away.

Comment: I've edited, it's now in the N panel > Edit > Bsurfaces. Yes I agree, some functions should be more quickly accessible