# How can I merge end vertices of two bezier curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

How can I merge the two bezier vertices occupying the same space pictured below? Typically, I merge bezier vertices like so:

1. Make sure the vertices are occupying the same space.
2. Select both vertices and hit F to create a segment.
3. Select one of the original vertices and hit X -> Vertices to delete the vertex that is no longer needed (this usually takes some trial and error).

This method worked for the vertex in the upper left of the image, which fused a straight horizontal segment to a curved segment. However, when I try to delete one of the original vertices to avoid having a segment between two vertices in the same position, it messes up one side of the curve or the other.

[image]

Comment: I think you can't merge or fuse control points in blender (yet). Your issue is in keeping the shape of the curve after deleting on of thr two control poits, right? Can't you adjust the shape later using the remaining control point (with free or vector hande type to make the sharp corner...)?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92912/can-i-set-the-start-point-of-a-bezier-curve/