Camera animation - path creation - Walking effect
Hi there sorry again for bothering you guys with what might be something rudimentary, but i am having trouble animating a camera and make it look like someone is walking in the maze i have created.
So this is the maze and the solution is the black path i have highlighted.

I have tried animating the camera using the "follow path" method but for some reason the camera instead of following the shape from start to finish it only follows the outlines.
Here is how the camera looks when i have the "follow path" on the camera.


I think it is important to say that this "solution" of the maze that i am trying to make the camera go trough is imported from illustrator along side the with the maze could that be the reason i am not being able to make the animation of the camera correctly ??
I also tried creating a new path with bezier curves but i'm not being able to make straight lines then curved ones like i have right now.
If someone can help me with this i would be appreciated.
Regards
ASilva
Edit: blender file link bellow in case it is needed, only have the Maze, the solution and the floor cuz i was testing a walk/fly mode of the camera with gravity but did not look so good.


Hello could you please share your file? Only keep the curve and camera if the rest is not useful: https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots hi there i just shared the blend file.

For the moment your camera has no reason to move, you need to either keyframe the Offset value of the Follow Path constraint, or select the curve, go into the Data panel > Path Animation > keyframe the Evaluation Time value

@moonboots humm i think there might be some communication problem from my part. What i am having trouble with is not animating the camera ... but making the path a single line with smooth curves so i can simulate a POV of a character walking in the maze. The current path i have is imported from illustrator and the camera kinda looks like the does laps around it instead of starting and finishing.
Was i able to clarify the situation better ?? the problem with the path and not the camera witch is i why i looking for alt ways to create the path.

OK I've tried an answer, tell me if I understand correctly your question

Fo the moment you have 2 parallel curves:

Remove the parrallel curve in order to have only one and choose 3D instead of 2D:

To get round corners change the handle type with V > Automatic:

Then switch the Transform Pivot Points to Individual Origins and scale down the vertices as much as needed:

Also you could make the camera go up and down so that it looks more like a camera walking: create a location keyframe, select the Z location track in the Graph Editor, and in the N panel > Modifiers > add a Noise modifier:


i have a feeling that this is exactly what i need but ... how should i remove the "2 parallel curves" to only 1 curve ?? should i like delete the vertices of the other curve 1 by 1 ??

it looks like it's one unique curve that is closed, you need to select all the vertices and delete (X)

Ok i will try that.

So i was able to convert this to only 1 curve and set the fill mode to none, how ever the curve merge it self, and does not look like your example.
Here take a look - https://i.imgur.com/07wXIqE.png

Yes you need to select the first and last vertices and press X > Delete Segments

hum ok ok ok thanks, now quick question does blender allow to set witch one is the first and last vértice ?

If you're talking about a closed curve, take a look at my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92912/can-i-set-the-start-point-of-a-bezier-curve
