converted from mesh to curves, some edges not highlighted when selected
after converting from meshed to curves, some edge not highlighted when selected. why is it and how to fix? thanks.
2 edges are not highlighted when I selected all.


That is the starting or closing segment of a spline and is represented in a different color. That is normal, and there is nothing to fix. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92912/can-i-set-the-start-point-of-a-bezier-curve

As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said, this is the closing segment. His linked answer is focusing on first points and spline direction etc., but this doesn't apply here because you cannot change these things on a polyline which you have there, only on Bézier splines. The actual reason of the different display of this segment is to indicate that this is not a "real" segment between two connected points, but an automatically generated segment which only exists because the spline is set to be cyclic, so if you would uncheck Cyclic U in the properties, this would be the segment that disappears.

@GordonBrinkmann You can change the first point and the direction of a Poly type spline, much like a Bezier or NURBS. The segment will always be there though, regardless of the place, for any of the available types.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos My Blender throws an error message when I try to do that, saying it has to be a Bézier spline ‍♂️

That is strange, could you show an example file? I do that quite frequently. Here is my typical workflow: create a mesh plane, convert to curve (by default poly), use it as bevel object on any other curve object. If you have blackface culling turned on in your viewport you will notice that by default the bevel object will be inside out and needs reversing. If you reverse the direction it will display fine.

Side note: Using Blender 4.2.5 and the Curve Tools add-on, for a Poly type spline, I can use "Switch Direction" (as Duarte) but not "Set First Points" (as Gordon, with the message: "All splines must be of Bezier type").
